# i'm having a trouble changing my liquid base color

Tags: modeling, materials, edit-mode

so i'm currently adding a base color to my liquid but the color end up changing both of my cup and my liquid (pict 1) i have also made a new materials but it won't change a single color and stayed like this (pict 2), is there any possible way to fix this?

[image: pict 1]

[image: pict 2]

Comment: you must make sure that you've assigned one color to an object (or part of the mesh) and the other color to the other one.

Comment: sorry but may i ask you to do me a favor doing it step by step?? i'm kinda new to blender haha

Comment: select the object, go in Edit mode, select the part of the mesh you want to have a certain color and in the panel on your right choose the right color and click Assign. Go back to Object mode and same thing for the other object.

Comment: it works, thank you so much! :)